# Is it possible to find a $2 × 2$ matrix $M$ for which the equation $M\vec{x} = \vec{p}$ has the following properties?

Tags: matrices, determinant, solution-verification, matrix-equations

> **QUESTION:** Answer as a series of four letters $(Y$ for Yes and $N$ for No$)$ in order.

> Is it possible to find a $2 × 2$ matrix $M$ for which the equation $M\vec{x} = \vec{p}$ has:

> $(a)$ no solutions for some but not all $\vec{p}$; exactly one solution for all other $\vec{p} ?$

> $(b)$ exactly one solution for some but not all $\vec{p}$; more than one solution for all other $\vec{p} ?$

> $(c)$ no solutions for some but not all $\vec{p}$; more than one solution for all other $\vec{p} ?$

> $(d)$ no solutions for some $\vec{p}$, exactly one solution for some $\vec{p}$ and more than one solution for some $\vec{p} ?$

---

**MY ANSWER:** Looking at the equation we can deduce some basic information as follows-

> ***case 1**: if det$(M)$ is non zero*
> Then the system has **a** unique solution that is $\vec{x}=M^{-1}\vec{p}$.

> ***case 2**: if det$(M)$ is zero*

$$ case \space 2.a$$

If $\vec{p}$ is also zero then clearly $\vec{x}=\frac{0}0$ has infinite number of solutions..

$$case \space 2.b$$

If $\vec{p}$ is not zero then $\vec{x}$ is of the form $\frac{non-zero}{zero}$ which is inconsistent..

Following this knowledge let us examine the options one by one-

> **(a)**

For us to have no solution, $M$ **must** have a zero determinant and $\vec{p}$ may take any non-zero value. But in that case, we **cannot** have exactly one solution for **any** $\vec{p}$. Therefore, $(a)$ is false $(N)$.

> **(b)**

For us to have *exactly* one solution, $det(M)≠0$. Then, we cannot have more than one solution for **any** $\vec{p}$. So, this too is false $(N)$.

> **(c)**

As said before, no solution occurs **only** when $det(M)=0$ **and** $\vec{p}≠0$. And if we choose $\vec{p}=0$ here then we have more than one (actually infinite) number of solutions. So this is possible.. $(Y)$.

> **(d)**

Clearly, the three conditions given cannot hold *simultaneously* for some **given** $M$. So it is false $(N)$.

---

Are my reasoning correct? Is there a better way to solve this equation?

> Also, it would be much help if someone can solve it geometrically.. Since, I am keen to know that approach.

Thank you so much in advance **:)**

Comment: This is just the _Kronecker-Capelli theorem_ and you have to prove the system is consistent iff $\operatorname{rank}(M)=\operatorname{rank}(M_a)$ where $M_a$ is the augmented matrix. If $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is invertible, as you said $\det M\ne0$, rank of the augmented matrix cannot exceed $\operatorname{rank}(M)$, so you're dealing with a _Cramer's system_. If a solution is unique, then the dimension of the solution space $\Omega$ is $0$. Bear in mind : $$\dim\Omega=n-\operatorname{rank}(M)$$ You haven't proven anything rigorously. You have to mention linear _(in)dependency_.

Comment: In a $2D$ space, $\det(M)$ is interepreted as the area of the parallelogram spanned by the column vectors. If $\det(M)=0$, then the column vectors are linearly dependent and you have a line.